# SQL Query to display records categorically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, tabular

I have my query displaying output as displayed below

```
`UserName   Status   Count`  
`A          Pass      32`
`A          fail      2`
`A          Hold      4`
`B          Fail      12`
`C          Pass      40`
`C          Fail      4`
`C          Hold      3`
`D          Pass      2`
```

I want to have output to be displayed, First record as username C and its details, second, A and its details. I'm trying to get Top 5 records with high pass status, and its related username records. I do not want to leave the 6th record if that username exists in the Top 5. Kindly help

Sorry I'm unable to format in a tabular format.

Comment: Is "tabular-data" a RDBMS? If not, which brand of SQL are you using?

Comment: can you provide the sample output you need . you only need to show the records with status = 'pass"?

Comment: Also, the table structures that you're using would be helpful.

Comment: I using SQL 2012 . The tabular data provided above is the output of my query.

Comment: OUTPUT should be, Top 5 records and C having maximum number as Pass status, should be displayed first and other records related to UserName 'C' should be followed. After that UserName 'A' and its record. Since we retrieve Top 5 , i donot want to miss UserName 'A' last record , since it will ignored when selecting Top 5.

Comment: Oh, so you don't want the top 5 users, but really only 5 records in the results, starting with the top user. So Output would be C-Pass, C-fail, C-Hold, A-Pass, A-fail? But what does "i donot want to miss UserName 'A' last Record" mean then? Do you want five records plus as many as are needed to show all missing records of the users already shown?

Comment: What shall be done in a case of ties, i.e. several users with the same top count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired listing order is relatively simple:

```
select top 6 * from #tbl INNER JOIN (
  SELECT UserName u, cnt pc FROM #tbl WHERE Status='Pass'
  ) ord ON u=UserName ORDER BY pc desc,status desc
```

However, limiting it to 5 rows, in case the first result sets are not complete, is not that easy. I am still trying ...

**Edit**:

Well, after a few more tries I figured out, that when you limit the output lines to a certain maximum number, depending on the data structure, you might end up with two less records if you insist that all lines of a user are always listed completely. Therefore, if we limit the output to 6 lines it will be possible that the list will end at line 4 if the next user would be supplying 3 more lines. Having accepted that, you could use the following:

```
;WITH cnts AS ( SELECT 
  UserName un,
  SUM(CASE Status 
           WHEN 'Pass' THEN 10000   --  weighing system
           WHEN 'Hold' THEN 100     --  to sort the results ...
                       ELSE 1 END * cnt) scr, -- --> score for sorting
  COUNT(*) ncnt                     --  row count per UserName
  FROM #tbl GROUP BY UserName
)
SELECT UserName,Status,cnt,scr,acnt FROM #tbl INNER JOIN (
 SELECT un,scr,(SELECT SUM(ncnt) FROM cnts WHERE scr>=c.scr) acnt 
 FROM cnts c WHERE (SELECT SUM(ncnt) FROM cnts WHERE scr>=c.scr) <=6 
) srt ON UserName=un
 ORDER BY scr DESC, UserName, Status desc
```

See [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421953/up-to-six-top-results).

The subquery `(SELECT SUM(ncnt) FROM cnts WHERE scr>=c.scr)` represents an accumulated line count which I use in the `where` clause of the `srt`-subquery to limit the output.

Contrary to my first approach I now sort internally according to `scr`, an internal score which I calculate by summing up all pass/hold/fail-counts with a different weighing factor. Without doing this, a user without a single 'pass' would never get listed, even if no other user was doing any better.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE_UserRanking AS (
    SELECT
        UserID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS user_rank
    FROM
        dbo.User_Scores S
    WHERE
        S.Status = 'Pass'
    GROUP BY
        UserID
)
SELECT
    U.UserName,
    S.Status,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    CTE_UserRanking R
INNER JOIN dbo.Users U ON U.UserID = R.UserID
INNER JOIN dbo.Scores S ON S.UserID = R.UserID
WHERE
    R.user_rank <= 5
GROUP BY
    U.UserID,
    U.UserName,
    S.Status
ORDER BY
    R.user_rank
```

Comment: Where do you get the column `UserID` from? And the same applies to the tables `Users` and `Scores` ... The OP only mentioned a single tabular output which serves as a pseudo table.

Comment: I made some inferences about his table structures since he hasn't provided any yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use an analytic funtion to get the passed rate per user, get the top 5, and order by passed rate.

```
select username, status, cnt
from
(
  select top(5) username, status, cnt, sum(case when status = 'Pass' then cnt else 0 end)
                                       over (partition by username) as passed
  from mytable
  order by 4 desc
) top5
order by 
  passed desc, 
  username, 
  case status when 'Pass' then 1 when 'fail' then 2 else 3 end;
```

(I took the liberty to call your count column cnt, as COUNT is a reserved word in SQL and would better not be chosen for a column name.)